# How is the flow of the execution of this fibonacci function

Tags: javascript

I found this `fibonacci function`.

I know that there are a lot of examples out there. But I can't figure out anything about this one.

```js
const fibonacci = (num) => {
   if(num == 0 || num == 1) {
       return [0, 1];
   } else {
       let result = fibonacci(num -1);
       result.push(result[result.length - 1] + result[result.length - 2]);
       return result;
   }
}

const result = fibonacci(7);
console.log(result);
```

Here at the end, I get printed at console `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`

When I send some number for example - 7 - as an argument in the function ( there the parameter name is `num` ), it gets in the ELSE BLOCK.

Therewith recursion, the function is called again, but now `num` gets decremented until it gets 1.

When it gets 1 it returns [0,1] so basically to start with the 'default values' to add the sum of the last two numbers.

So now at line 5 by `let result = fibonacci(num -1);` we have [0,1].

After that with this code `result.push(result[result.length - 1] + result[result.length - 2]);`

We get the sum of 0 and 1 which is 1.

We return it to the result variable. And it goes on until the number 7.

I don't understand how it 'counts' that it needs to go until number 7.

In the developer tools when i debug i see that after first return in the else block after we get the default one [0,1] - it now INCREMENTS the num number in the function it self until it reaches 7.

How is this happening ?

Comment: What are you talking about, where would `num` get _incremented_? It starts with 7, and only gets _decrement_  on each of the recursive calls.

Comment: Try in developer tools - debugging please

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = fibonacci(num -1);   // A
result.push(result[result.length - 1] + result[result.length - 2]); // B
return result; // C
```

When you execute line A, you leave on the call stack lines B and C.
When your function does a `return` you go back to B, with `num` equals to what it was before stacking the call, then in C you `return` again, unstacking yet another call, until there are no more calls in the stack.

This would cause an infinite loop (always calling num -1, so 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3...) or crash when you don't have more space in your call stack. But you avoid that with your

```
   if(num == 0 || num == 1) {
       return [0, 1];
```

Because that makes 1 not to stack any more calls. Btw it's better to define an error with num < 0 (more mathematically sound) or directly return 0,1 for every value lesser than 2 (more pragmatic)

Comment: Thanks for that. But why `num` it gets incremented after it goes on STACK B  ?

Comment: imagine you get a deck of cards. You find 7 of spades and you put it on the table, then you find 6 and you put it on top of the 7, then 5,4,3,2...and you get the ace of diamonds. this is the signal to start REMOVING cards from the pile. So you don't get the number on the card incremented after removing the one on top, you just happen to find back the old value that the card always had

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation – malarres. But why it goes back ? I thought it will stop after the first return in else block , how it continues ?

Comment: this is not specific to recursion, but to calling functions in general. When you call a function, after the called function returns you go back to the point that function was called

Comment: Why it goes back - to increment the number until 7 i meaned